# Where to Download Singularitygs v1.2.0RC1

Tags: singularitygs

Is there a way to download the new RC so I do not have to use Compass or Ruby? I have looked on Github.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from the [releases section of the project](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/releases/tag/v1.2.0.rc.1). Please be aware that it requires [Breakpoint 2.4.x](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/releases/tag/v2.4.1) and will only compile using a compiler that has feature parity with Sass 3.3, which as of right now is only the Sass 3.3.0.rc.x gems (so Ruby is still required at the moment for that gem)